# Error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-graphics.so.2.2.0

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, sfml

Full Error:
`error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-graphics.so.2.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

This is probably the quintillionth time I've run into this error with SFML. This error oddly only occurs when running the executable, rather than during compilation. I don't know what is causing the error (apart from the program not finding the file), since it worked like a charm before I reinstalled Ubuntu. I've tried `sudo ldconfig` and I have used `sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev`, but I don't link SFML using it, but from an extracted archive.

Comment: if you're building from source, make sure you include the `.so` in the directory of the executable.

Comment: @OMGtechy what do you mean 'include the `.so` in the directory of the executable'? Like put it in the linker settings (I use Code::Blocks btw)

Comment: What is the error? Try compiling your exe using `-z defs`, do you get any errors?

Comment: The error is `cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, but I have all the necessary files in the folder with it

Comment: @bboy3577 if you built it yourself, you need to include the `.so` file that gets built in the same directory as the executable. This is because it needs to load it at runtime. If you're not building yourself, it's irrelevant :)

Comment: @OMGtechy The `.so` files are definitely in the same directory as the executable, in fact I've pretty much put the `.so` files everywhere that makes sense.

Comment: @bboy3577 you should add everything you've tried to this, so people can skip these questions.I'll look at starting a chat room for youu

Comment: @bboy3577 join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79575/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libsfml-graphics-so-2-2-0)

Comment: @OMGtechy I need 2 more rep to talk in chat

Comment: @bboy3577 voted up one of your good questions, try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer relies on `libsfml-dev` being installed on your system. The way to fix it is removing all SFML options from the Search Directories>Linker, then make sure the linker settings looks something like this:

[image: Linker Settings example]

This means that CodeBlocks will link to the default place. Afterwards recompile the code (Edit the code so CodeBlocks will actually compile it). I was running g++ 4.9.2 but I'm not sure if the default 4.8.2 works, or if it makes any difference at all.